# Causes of permanent hand damage and other effects it may have

Tags: science-based

Basically, I have a musician type character who has permanent hand damage in both hands that prevents him from playing instruments. This information can also be used by those who wants to learn about hand damage in general. I want to know what are the different types of hand damage, how they can be caused and what other side effects it may have in day to day life as befits the

> How to achieve a specified effect in a defined world, including by the use of biology, technology or magic, while maintaining in-universe consistency

part of the guidelines. The end goal is to prevent the musician from playing instruments ever again.

They must fit the following criteria:

- no amputations involved, they may get a lot of physical damage, but the hand should still stay intact
- may or may not be from an accident
- may or may not be due to some sort of disease (real life disease)
- must be permanent, meaning the hands will never be the same ever again
- has to be applicable on an average teenager kid (13-19) prior to being disabled, meaning no stuff like old age arthritis or getting shot by alien lasers
- has to be applicable to modern times (aka 21st century),meaning stuff like cures/techniques that have been invented now are available for the character

Comment: Phil Collins played the drums so much in his life that he destroyed his wrist muscles despite all the care he took. You may look at him for inspiration for your character. Also watch the movie Whiplash for a (fictional) very young drummer who nearly got into that same condition.

Comment: "may or may not" bullet points should be omitted entirely as they aren't providing any useful information.  And "a normal healthy teenager" is not a description that matches someone who has permanent hand damage.  This is a disabled person.  Arthritis also affects young people.

Comment: @StephenG Though the bullet points containing "may or may not be" might not really mean anything to most people, it'll help some folks who get stuck at only considering accidents. As for the last point, I have edited it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I'd ***strongly*** suggest looking *thoroughly* through this thread, as a lot of the points there will cross-fertilise with your question...

[[Could a character survive having a device torn out of their radial artery? + effects](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/111044/could-a-character-survive-having-a-device-torn-out-of-their-radial-artery-eff/111080#111080])

Secondly, I'm the one there on that thread talking about massive traumatic damage to a wrist, and the long-term consequences it has, both physical and psychological, as this happened to me now 6 years ago. I *was* a musician, and am slowly recovering some ability to play.

Traumatic damage such that both radius and ulna were shattered, and subsequently pinned to metal plates; muscle and ligament traumatic removal; nerve damage and surgical re-routing of both radial nerve and radial artery to fit around said metal plate: radial artery beneath plate, radial nerve above. Large palmar planar ligament devitalised and removed; parted into "repair parts" for other damaged ligaments. No musclemass above nerve passing over plate means huge vulnerability to cold/heat/impact and potential for catastrophic further nerve damage.

This results in ongoing **neuropathy**: pain, fiery tingling and numbness (often simultaneously), feelings of boiling water pouring along inner surface of wrist/hand/fingers/thumb (as though hand is hollow volume); sporadic mid to low strength muscle activation with attendant loss of fine motor control, and a deeply frustrating re-learning curve when slight nerve recovery begins - as though the entire hand was somehow deprogrammed and you need to not only relearn its proper use but also reprogram drivers for each individual muscle and all muscle group *on the fly* whilst relearning.

This then impacts daily life in all aspects: washing dishes, brushing teeth, brushing hair, shaving, exercising - as one cannot ***count*** on one's own hand's reporting feedback as accurate, one learns to compensate positionally and behaviourally, as one may, *without warning*, suddenly lose grip on something which one's hand *tells* one it has securely held. It's disconcerting as hell to be getting "yup, we're squeezing that bowl *really* hard" feedback and nonetheless ***watch*** the damned thing *slide out of your grip* and have to dive with the other hand to catch it. I broke * a **lot** * of bowls and glasses during early and mid recovery. Exercise is deeply frustrating, as you cannot actually activate muscles properly which are being enervated by a damaged, neuropathic nerve, as the signal doesn't reach the muscle with the brain-intended intensity - you ***send*** "Curl bicep at 90% force" and the muscle *receives* 50% of that signal strength, so you get a bicep activation of 45%, which of course makes it really hard to maintain any muscular strength, let alone recover from the horrifying atrophy you get from having had a limb hang like a dead fish for 6+ months.

For those curious - what my neurologists told me: neuropathy affects apparent signal strength due to the nerve signal's *"activation strength"* **not** being absolute, but being **relative** to its *resting state* signal - it's the magnitude of the delta, the difference between the two that is the intensity of activation. A damaged, neuropathic nerve is sending constant low (or mid) level "I'm damaged - OW" signals in its resting state, so the relative delta between the highest-intensity signal and the noisy resting state is lower - hence lower resulting activation intensity. Sort of like background noise in radio - if you want to think of it in communications theory terms, the signal to noise ratio is all jacked up. The more damaged or noisy a nerve is, the lower its possible highest activation signal, and the weaker the possible muscle response, no matter *how* big & strong the muscle was to begin with, *or* how determined the brain is. You can imagine how this impacts exercise.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As someone who has dislocated and fractured his left leg at the same time, I'm quite familiar with your feelings about therapy. But that aside, by "am slowly recovering some ability to play" do you mean that your hand is healing? Or that you are slowly adapting to it? Also, how worse do you think it could get before the "my hand won't move at all" line is crossed?

Comment: @Foolish - it was at the won’t move at all for ~6 months or so... 3 months no arm or hand, then slowly arm came back - hand started recovering a bit starting 3 months after that. I have limited mobility, strength, proprioception and sensation, and am told there will be little (5% at max) improvement from here forward. I have three times ‘relost’ the hand, losing all remaining sensation and motor function: once from over enthusiastic exercise, once from bumping the exposed nerve, and once from infection - somewhere between dispiriting, terrifying and angering - the first time blankly terrifying

Answer (score 4):

Broadly speaking there are a large number of [musculoskeletal disorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musculoskeletal_disorder) you can have that can effect motor functions. These may not always be local to the hands/arms and may have other larger effects. Some of these cases it degrades over time and function is lost slowly, while in others it may never have existed or is lost rapidly and permanently.

Nerve damage (often as the result of trauma) can cause one to lose motor function. I had a buddy who was in a nasty motorcycle accident at age 19 and lost the use of one hand as a result of nerve damage. He actually lost complete use, movement and feeling below the elbow. There was an attempt to repair/replace the nerve that was unsuccessful and outlook for it healing on its own is basically non existent.

With out use of your hands day to day life can be hard. In no specific order the following things require a fair bit of dexterity and often two hands thus your life would be quite impacted if you had no use of your hands.

- Basic personal hygiene (tooth brushing, cleaning, etc)
- Typing (in todays modern world pretty much everyone interacts with a computer somehow
- Eating/Preparing food
- Operating a vehicle
- Basic tasks potentially needed for employment
- Opening door knobs and other similar tasks

Comment: I'd like more information concerning the extent of the damage of your buddy's hand. Is he still able to move his fingers/wrist? Is he still able to feel anything with his damaged hand? How bad must the nerve damage be to attain that level of function loss? If it was any lesser, would that make it not permanent?

Comment: @Foolish I have added a bit. Im not sure how bad it needs to be to not be permanent but he has no feeling, motion, or use of his forearm/hand anymore. A nerve replacement was attempted unsuccessfully (im not sure why).

Comment: after a fall I've next to no use of 2 fingers in my left hand. Doctor's response?  We don't know what's wrong, can only hope it gets better in time... Can still use the hand, but limited due to pain and loss of strength and dexterity.